# MERN stack (JavaScript) app not rendering anything though "root" tag

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, deployment

I am deploying a react full-stack app to heroku... It deploys with no issues and in the network tag (debugging) it appears that everything has loaded BUT nothing renders through the `<div id="root"></div>` tag. I have included a heroku postbuild script such as...

`"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"`

HEROKU logs with `heroku logs --tail` look good - all 200's or 304's

I have an express server that SHOULD be serving up the react app which I believe it is as the logo and other static files load properly and display. Here is a screenshot of my react app (notice the root has no children). I have tried the following fixes with no luck...

1. client side package.json `"homepage": ".";`
2. added various settings/configurations to react-router-dom logic such as `baseline={"/"}`
3. Have changed and tried various express routes for any route that doesn't match any specific server routes
4. I did SUCCESSFULLY deploy a static build to digitalocean.com but the REST api's stopped working so thats not a proper solution for me - uploaded build folder as a static resource

[image]

My express server looks like this...

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const config = require("config");
// init middleware
// const http = require("http");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoDB = require("./config/db.js");
// const server = http.createServer(app);
const path = require("path");
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const helmet = require("helmet");
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: config.get("wasabiSecretAccessKey"),
    accessKeyId: config.get("wasabiAccessKey"),
    region: config.get("wasabiRegion")
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoDB();

app.options('*', cors());
app.use('*', cors());
app.use(cors());


app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: "20mb"
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: "20mb",
    extended: false
}));


const limiter = rateLimit({
    max: 100,// max requests
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000, // remove the last 1000 for production
    message: 'Too many requests' // message to send
}); 

app.use(xss());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(mongoSanitize());
app.use(limiter);

// routes go here...
app.use("/add/card/make/payment", require("./routes/payments/checkout.js"));
app.use("/register", require("./routes/auth/register/index.js"));
app.use("/sign-in", require("./routes/auth/signin/index.js"));
app.use("/upload/agreement/consent/rules", require("./routes/rules/signRulesSheet.js"));
app.use("/gather/existing/cards", require("./routes/payments/gather/gatherExistingCards.js"));
app.use("/change/primary/card", require("./routes/payments/change/makePrimary.js"));
app.use("/add/additional/card/payments", require("./routes/payments/add/addPaymentMethod.js"));
app.use("/post/blog/post", require("./routes/blogs/create/createBlogPost.js"));
app.use("/gather/all/blogs", require("./routes/blogs/gather/index.js"));
app.use("/contact/form/connect", require("./routes/contact/sendMessage.js"));
app.use("/gather/individual/blog", require("./routes/blogs/gather/gatherIndividualBlog.js"));
app.use("/update/time/schedule", require("./routes/tours/schedule/scheduleChange.js"));
app.use("/gather/times/per/date", require("./routes/tours/gather/gatherTimes.js"));
app.use("/send/request/tour", require("./routes/tours/email/sendTourRequest.js"));
app.use("/make/payment/existing", require("./routes/payments/existing/index.js"));


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));


app.get('/', function(_, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      };
    });
});
app.get('*', function(_, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      };
    });
});
  
app.get('/*', function(_, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      };
    }); 
});


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")))


    app.get('/', function(_, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
          };
        }); 
    });
    app.get('*', function(_, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
          };
        }); 
    });
      
      app.get('/*', function(_, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
          };
        });  
    });

}; 


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

My network tab looks like this...

[image]

lastly my react-router-dom setup on the client-side looks like this...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HomepageMain from "./pages/homepage/index.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import PaymentsIndividualPage from "./pages/payments/individual/index.js";
import LoginPage from "./pages/auth/login/index.js";
import RegistrationPage from "./pages/auth/register/index.js";
import { NotificationContainer } from 'react-notifications';
import ContactMainPage from "./pages/contact/index.js";
import RulesPage from "./pages/rules/index.js";
import ViewCardsPage from "./pages/payments/cards/view/index.js";
import NotAuthenticated from "./pages/404.js";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import _ from "lodash";
import BlogsHomepagePage from "./pages/blogs/home/index.js";
import CreateBlogPage from "./pages/blogs/create/createBlog.js";
import BlogsIndividualPage from "./pages/blogs/individual/index.js";
import TeamPagePage from "./pages/team/index.js";
import ToursManageMainPage from "./pages/tours/manage/index.js";
import ViewAppointmentsPage from "./pages/tours/view/viewAppointments.js";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <NotificationContainer/>
      <Router basename={"/"} >
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomepageMain} />
          <Route exact path="/payment-page-package" component={PaymentsIndividualPage} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={RegistrationPage} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactMainPage} />
          <Route exact path="/rules-regulations" component={RulesPage} />
          <Route exact path="/payments-view" component={this.props.unique_id !== null ? ViewCardsPage : NotAuthenticated} />
          <Route exact path="/blogs-homepage" component={BlogsHomepagePage} />
          <Route exact path="/create-a-blog" component={CreateBlogPage} />
          <Route exact path="/blog-individual-:id" component={BlogsIndividualPage} />
          <Route exact path="/team" component={TeamPagePage} />
          <Route exact path="/manage-schedule" component={ToursManageMainPage} />
          <Route exact path="/tour-appointments" component={ViewAppointmentsPage} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    unique_id: _.has(state.auth.data, "unique_id") ? state.auth.data.unique_id : null
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { })(App);
```

PLEASE help as my client is expecting their project soon - idk why it won't display - I've uploaded tons of apps with great success but this one has been a real pain in my butt